# SQLite3 (Python): execute() command not working with string parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm writing code that takes a user-inputted string and binds it to a SQLite command through a parameter.

I've gotten this functionality to work when the string is already embedded in the query (see first example under "these lines do work"), and this binding method works with integers just fine (see second example).

```
testname = "\"EJtheDJ\"" #this would be user-inputted, but I get the same issue when I initialize it this way

#this line doesn't work
c.execute("select lastfm from usernames where discordname=?", (testname,))

#these lines do work
#c.execute("select lastfm from usernames where discordname=\"EJtheDJ\"")
#c.execute("select integer1 from test where integer2=?", (num,)) #num=3

print(c.fetchone()) #prints out "None"
```

My syntax seems 100% correct according to all the tutorials and forum threads I've looked at. I don't normally make posts here (in fact this is my first time), but I'm completely stumped on this and felt it was my only option. Any help would be massively appreciated. I'm running this on a CentOS server with Python 3.6, if that helps.

**Edit**: Turns out I just needed to do away with the escaped quotes. `testname = EJtheDJ` works perfectly.

Comment: Don't put quotes in the parameter value. These will be added by the library when the parameter is substituted into the command.

Comment: Do not add escaped quotes for your string, the module does that for you.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks so much!